# jquery 1.7 click event after append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onclick

I'm playing around with event-delegation from http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/
.I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="A small web app to manage todos">
        <title>TO-DO jQuery Tests</title>

    <!--src attribute in the <script> element must point to a copy of jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "article" ).on( "click","a", function() {
                console.log( "The ID attribute of the link is: " + $(this).attr('id'));
            });
            //The .append()method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection -->
            $( "#test-container" ).append("<article> <a href=\"#\"id='link-2'>Link 2</a> </article>" );
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test-container">
        <article>
            <a href="#" id="link-1">Link 1</a>
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

When I click on Link2 I get no output on the console? Why isn't the event-handling working?

Comment: From the [`.on` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/): *"**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`**."*

Comment: It took me so long to realize why it was a problem until I noticed that you're appending new `<article>` elements to the div. I thought you were just adding more `<a>` elements to the existing `<article>` element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to bind to the closest static parent.
This case `test-container`.

```
$( "#test-container" ).on( "click","article a", function() {
    // your code
});
```

Comment: Would be better as "article a" not just "a"

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the second link is added dynamically and the click binding happens before the second link exists. That's why it has no affect on it.

Your code should look like this (instead of `$(document)` you can also use any static parent container as Ricardo pointed out):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document ).on( "click","article a", function() {
        console.log( "The ID attribute of the link is: " + $(this).attr('id'));
    });
    //The .append()method inserts the specified content as the last child of each element in the jQuery collection -->
    $( "#test-container" ).append("<article> <a href=\"#\"id='link-2'>Link 2</a> </article>" );
});
```

Comment: It better would be to swap "#test-container" and document in the click line.